# Need Traffic Accident Data

Tags: data, traffic

I am graduate student studying in GIS.

My project is related with traffic accidents, but I cannot find the traffic accident data online.

The scale could be a city or a state in US since I just started the project. I prefer bigger cities though, more accidents data will make the project more analyzable.

Is there any suggestion?

Comment: What country? Police and insurance companies *might* have some data but they might not want to share it.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour].  Your questions here should always provide details of your research so far into answering your own question, before telling us where you are now stuck.  I recommend that you use the **edit** button to revise your question with much more detail.  Firstly, I think we need to know what country you are looking for the data in.

Comment: It should in US. I think about that, and the data I need is not necessary last version. It could be back to 2005. I am thinking pull form google map, I do not know how difficult it will be.

Comment: Can't find it? Really? Pick a city name and Google on that with 'traffic accident GIS data'. Or even leave the city name off. I see pages and pages of results, several of which lead directly to pages with shapefile download links. Denver for example. Or New York (city, state, and county).

Comment: The [opendata.se] Stack Exchange looks like a good place to research/ask your question: https://opendata.stackexchange.com/search?q=traffic+accident

Answer (score 5):

I was always told that searching, finding, and processing your data [for a GIS project] is 80% of the work. That's the tough part. As a grad student, researching and finding data sources will be a necessary and essential task you'll need to master.

That said, you're looking for "open data." Just type in a few combinations of what you're looking for on Google ("traffic deaths") with the words "open data" or "open data portal" and you'll get closer to what you want. A few US cities have opened up data like this. I don't want to totally give away the answer for ethical reasons, but hopefully this will help. ;)

Scraping from Google Maps and that sort of thing takes some coding experience to get it done reasonably. Start with open data portals for now!